# Create Launcher Shortcut

Tags: desktop-shortcuts

I am using Debian and I want to make a icon on the launcher that I can click on to open my Teamspeak server. Currently, I have to go to the terminal and type the following commands.

```
cd /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64
./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```

This launches my Teamspeak 3 server, leaving the terminal open which is time consuming and annoying to have a terminal open solely for this purpose. In Ubuntu I just made a .desktop file and dragged the icon onto my launcher, which is miles better. Not sure how to do that on Debian though, can someone advise?

Comment: Which GUI? GNOME, XFCE, KDE, LXDE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a desktop file for **Teamspeak 3 server** and place it at `/usr/share/applications` directory and run `sudo  update-desktop-database`.

**how to create the desktop file**
open any text editor of your choice and place the lines bellow and save it with any name you want like teamspeak_3_server.desktop .

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
Icon=/path/to/teamspeak3/icon
Name=Teamspeak 3 server
GenericName=Teamspeak
Categories=Network;
```

Change the icon path if you want a fancy application icon.

I suggest to create a symlink for ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh to avoid the long line and change the `Exec=` line of the desktop file.

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh /usr/bin/ts3server`

Comment: I did the steps listed and I still do not see it in the launcher with an icon. I assume in Debian you can't add an icon directly to that "Activities" launcher pannel on the left, you just have to search for it once you've clicked "Activities"? The picture display is also not working. If I double click the .desktop, or click it on after searching on the "Activities" menu file it runs, so it's just not displaying it in the launcher properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. Apparently it just wasn't allowing me to save icons in the /usr/share/icons folder. So I made a folder within that icons folder and put the image there. After I modified my path it worked. Thanks

Comment: I know this is old, but what does the last directory do in the `sudo ln -s` command?. Want to do the same but my directory is different (`/home/mariel/Downloads/Programas/VESTA-x86_64/VESTA`) and don't know what to replace that with.

Comment: @Mariel It's just to create a symbolic link to the targeted script to avoid typing long.  If your executable file is **VESTA** then you can create a symlink to **/usr/bin** `sudo ln -s /home/mariel/Downloads/Programas/VESTA-x86_64/VESTA  /usr/bin/VESTA`

Comment: I did the command without the last part and the launcher still created. Was the last part necessary?

Comment: It's OK, but I think adding the executable name is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Xfce Panel](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start), you can add items to it.
Let's add the [Launcher plugin](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/launcher) to a favorite place.

(To make a Launcher drop the desktop files to the panel, it should not be dropped at the top of an existing icon. If the operation is difficult, let's use the [Add New Items dialog](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/add-new-items).)